# Rails query with has_many and belongs_to unexpected results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building a Rails app and have a model called Item. It belongs_to a Type, and has_many Types through ItemTypes.

When querying for Items by their has_many Types association I am expecting no results but I'm getting back items when they belong to that Type.

```
# models/item.rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_types
  has_many :types, through: :item_types
  belongs_to :type, inverse_of: :items
end

# models/type.rb
class Type < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items, inverse_of: :item_type, dependent: :nullify
end

# models/itemtype.rb
class ItemType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :type
end
```

Example (expected behaviors):

```
food = Type.create
pizza = Item.create(type: food)

irb> pizza.type
food

irb> pizza.types
[]
```

However, when I query for items with the associated item type and am expecting no results, I am getting back my item, even though there are no ItemType objects.

```
irb> Item.where(type: food)
pizza
irb> Item.where(types: food)
pizza
```

(pizza is still returned dispite the fact that pizza.types returns [])

I'm not sure what happening behind the scenes but I find this to be an unexpected behavior. Why is this happening and how can I get my `Item.where(types: food)` query to return no results?

Comment: Is this all.the code.youre running? .new doesn't save, and you should be using a .save or calling .create instead of new to build these. I suspect the results you see could be because you aren't saving and persisting things, so the state of the relationship hasn't been updated. Also, can you post your other models?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the other related models and updated the .new calls to .create since they do exist in the db. It seems like active record is having some issue differentiating between the has_many types and belongs_to type when querying those relations.

Comment: I've found that I can get the result I'm looking for by writing a longer query `Item.includes(:item_types).where(item_type: {type: food})` but I am still very interesting in learning why the original query doesn't work and how come the `has_many :types, through: :item_types` isn't respected in `Item.where(types: food)`

Comment: Is that still your exact model? You need to inherit from `ApplicationRecord`, as in `class Item < ApplicationRecord` vs what you have in yoru code above

Comment: There's not really enough information provided to determine why you're seeing what you're seeing. I provided a working example of something that does have expected behavior in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a working solution for this issue so I'll put it here for future readers.

The problem is that whether we query items by type or types, in `Item.where(type: food)` or `Item.where(types: food)` types is ambiguous and seems to refer to the belongs_to relationship defined in the Item model with `belongs_to :type`.

To get around this, to query Items by their ItemTypes you can first join the tables using `includes(:item_types)` and then are able to query on those ItemTypes where their Type is of a desired instance.

The resulting query that gives me the desired result is `Item.includes(:item_types).where(item_type: {type: food})`.

Answer (score 0):

Your models aren't quite correct; you need to inherit from `ApplicationRecord` if you're expecting these to work with the database. You should be using the generator to generate your models.

```
rails g model Item name:string
rails g model Type name:string
rails g model ItemType item:references type:references
```

Then, modify your models so they look like this:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_types
  has_many :types, through: :item_types
end

class Type < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :item_types
  has_many :items, through: :item_types
end

class ItemType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :type
end
```

Your syntax is fine for pseudocode, but the code below should actually work

```
carbs = Type.create(name: 'Carbs')
pizza = Item.create(name: 'Pizza')
carbs.items << pizza
```

You can also create items on the fly, as below:

```
carbs.items.create(name: 'Milkshake')
```

You then get access to things like:

```
carbs.items.first.name #=> 'Pizza'
pizza.types.map(&:name) #=> ['Carbs']
```

You'll want to look at the [association basics documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) for additional features.

Comment: These models don't quite demonstrate the behavior I am trying to explain. Items have a primary type which is defined as a belongs_to :type on the Item model. They also have any number of associated types which is defined as has_many :types, through: :item_types. 

The problem arises when both of these definitions are present on the Item model.